# ncftp - recursive deletion

Tags: ftp, recursion

I would like to recursively delete a folder and his subfolders.
I use ncftp.
This application provides rm and rmdir.

I already looked up the [manpage](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftp.html), but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works:

```
rm -rf directory
```

As someone pointed out, depending on the ncftp version it won't work. Try this syntax then:

```
rm -rf directory/*
```

Comment: Tried that already...

> rm -rf html
delete html: remote rmdir failed.
ncftp ... >

Comment: It won't work. At least not with every ncftp build. See the first answer for the proper syntax.

Comment: @monsune Updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `/*`, as in `rm -rf directory/*`

Comment: no, the other answer works just fine even without the star.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Thank you. Just when I was about to think that there was no solution with ncftp.